# What is "Lambda" in Heston's original paper on stochastic volatility models?

Tags: options, stochastic-processes

In his paper ([link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.139.3204&rep=rep1&type=pdf)), he has the equations:

> b1 = k + ƛ - (ρ * σ)
>
> b2 = k + ƛ

k is the rate of mean reversion, ρ is the correlation between the two Wiener processes, σ is vol of vol, what is ƛ?

I have yet to figure out what ƛ is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is on page 329 (which is the third page of the article) and represents the market price of volatility risk. I have copied below from the original article:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is the "price of volatility risk" (see Page 329)

When volatility can change the "attitude" of investors to these changes becomes important for pricing options. This like/dislike for vol increases is captured in the parameter $\lambda$. In practice vol goes up i.e. $dv$ is positive, in bad economic times, such as recessions, when $dC$ is negative. So $\lambda$ is negative.